# Python, Print to file without functionality of "\n"

Tags: python

I am trying to print string to file, but I want it this way:

```
string = "asdfasdf \n awefawe"
```

I want it to be printed as it is. so the file contains:

```
asdfasdf \n awefawe
```

AND NOT

```
asdfasdf
 awefawe
```

How do I do that? I tried:

```
f1=open('./testfile.txt', 'w+')
f1.write(body)
```

**Edit:** I don't want to change the string
I just want to print it as it is. Even to stdout. I don't care where. I want to know what the string contains. It is not only about `\n`

Comment: "I want to know what the string contains" -- FYI, In your example, your string contains a newline character.  It does not contain the characters `'\'` and `'n'` in sequence.

Comment: @codehorse: That won't work, even if you fix the syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't modify the code that sets the value of `string` (as suggested by the other answers), you can use one of the [Python-specific codecs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) that convert "special" characters to the equivalent Python-string-literal escape sequence:

```
>>> print "abc\ndef".encode("string_escape")
abc\ndef
```

If the string may contain non-ASCII characters you may want `unicode_escape` instead, depending on your larger requirements:

```
>>> print "Ā".encode("string_escape")
\xc4\x80
>>> print u"Ā".encode("unicode_escape")
\u0100
```

Technically `string_escape` can only be applied to *byte* strings, and `unicode_escape` to *Unicode* strings, but Python 2 lets you get away with using either as long as all the characters fall in the ASCII range (i.e. U+0000 through U+007F).  I'm not sure what the Python 3 equivalents are -- the `.encode` method seems to not exist on `bytes` objects in 3.2...

Comment: Finally,  a proper answer to this case.

Comment: @Nirock What? A lot... If you ask that as a question, i would probably close vote it as too broad..

Answer (score 4):

Modify the definition of `string` so that it ends up containing `\n` rather than a newline.  This can be done with either:

```
string = r"asdfasdf \n awefawe"
```

or:

```
string = "asdfasdf \\n awefawe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Python interprets `\n` within strings as a newline character. Therefore, to print a literal backslash, simply escape the backslash using another backslash, like so:

```
string = "asdfasdf \\n awefawe"
```

Comment: That doesn't help me much. I need it to be done with .replace, but I have many other strings that I have to escape.  Is there any way to print it as it is?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the backslash.

```
string = "asdfasdf \\n awefawe"
```